# Regular Expression_How to extract several matching patterns from a line?

Tags: python, regex

I have a .csv document consists of several lines. In each line I have tab separated informations such as,

```
name_1:ayse \t name_2:fatma \t birth_date_1:24 \t birth_date_2:august \t birth_date_3:2018 \t death_date:2100 \t location:turkey.
```

The sequence of these informations may not be same in each line and there many informations like this in each line.

What am I trying to do is to get a specific part of the string which only has "birth_date" information in it.

I am managed to get only all 3 strings related with birth date as follows

```
['birth_date_1', 'birth_date_2', 'birth_date_3']
```

with the help of below code.

```
 inputfile = open('ornek_data.csv','r',encoding="utf-8")

 for rownum, line in enumerate(inputfile):
    pattern_birth = re.compile(r"\w*birth_date\w*",re.IGNORECASE)
    if pattern_birth.search(line) is not None:
       a = re.findall("\w*birth_date\w*", line)
       print(a)
```

However what i want actually is to extact below list as output and write it in another document for each line.

```
['birth_date_1:24', 'birth_date_2:august', 'birth_date_3:2018']
```

I tried several other regular expressions methods such as below but I couldn't handle it. I will be glad if anyone can help me with this problem.

```
    for rownum, line in enumerate(inputfile):
        pattern_birth = re.compile(r"\w*birth_date\w*",re.IGNORECASE)
        if pattern_birth.search(line) is not None:
           a = re.findall("\w*birth_date.*?:$", line)
           print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"\w*birth_date.*?\s"` or `r"birth_date_\d:.*?\s"`

**Ex:**

```
import re

line = "name_1:ayse \t name_2:fatma \t birth_date_1:24 \t birth_date_2:august \t birth_date_3:2018 \t death_date:2100 \t location:turkey."
print(re.findall("\w*birth_date.*?\s", line))
```

**Output:**

```
['birth_date_1:24 ', 'birth_date_2:august ', 'birth_date_3:2018 ']
```

Comment: The trailing whitespace on each match is a bit of a wart, and will miss any field which is the last one in a line.

Comment: The information I am looking for generally in the middle of list so it won't be a problem for  my case. Thanks any way for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `regex` here.

Split on `'\t'` and check if the splitted contains `'birth_date'`, simple!:

```
s =  'name_1:ayse \t name_2:fatma \t birth_date_1:24 \t birth_date_2:august \t birth_date_3:2018 \t death_date:2100 \t location:turkey.'

print([x.strip() for x in s.split('\t') if 'birth_date' in x])
# ['birth_date_1:24', 'birth_date_2:august', 'birth_date_3:2018']
```

Comment: thank you, this one also seems like a fast approach.

Comment: Fastest and also inexpensive one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match what you are trying to extract, so you need to extend it.

As an aside, you should only `re.compile` once - the point of compilation is to avoid needing to parse the regex again.

There is also no need to check for no matches separately. Just loop over all the matches; if there are none, the loop will execute zero times.

```
pat = re.compile(r"\bbirth_date_\d+:\d+",re.IGNORECASE)

with open('ornek_data.csv','r',encoding="utf-8") as inputfile:
    for rownum, line in enumerate(inputfile):
        for a in pat.findall(line):
            print(rownum, a)
```

The `\w*` wasn't doing anything useful (if you don't care if it's there or not, as the `*` quantifier does, why search for it?) whereas `\b` requires the match to occur at a word boundary (so adjacent to whitespace or punctuation, or beginning or end of line). `\d` matches a digit and `:` simply matches itself.

If this is a well-formed CSV file, maybe instead use a CSV reader and print the fields which match `startswith('birth_date_')`